# Laravel Validation using rule?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I currently have validation in the validation request:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rule['name'] = "required";
    $rule['provider'] = "required";

    switch ($this->provider) {
        case 'cloudName1':
            $rule['api_key'] = "required";
            break;
        case 'cloudName2':
            $rule['key'] = "required";
            $rule['secret'] = "required";
            break;
    }

    return $rule;
}
```

Is there Laravel rule I can use instead of using `switch()` condition to do same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

You can use Laravel's `required_if` rule -

```
required_if:anotherField,value,...
```

> The field under validation must be present and not empty if the
>   anotherfield field is equal to any value.

This is how you can implement it into your code:

```
$rule[
    'name' => 'required',
    'provider' => 'required',
    'api_key' => 'required_if:provider,cloudName1',
    'key' => 'required_if:provider,cloudName2',
    'secret' => 'required_if:provider,cloudName2',
];
```

See [Laravel Validation Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: You didnt use `anotherfield` for `required_with` - you just used value?

Comment: See my updated answer, I think this would work, sorry for inconvenience!

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct. `key` and `secret` is required when `provider` value is cloudName2 for example

Comment: I've updated the answer, please use required_if, check it out